# permitAll of requestMatchers doesn't work on "/" pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm making website and I have to use SecurityFilterChain.
BTW, the start page - localhost:8080/ is always secured.
When I enter localhost:8080/, browser always want me to sign in.
How can I adjust permitAll on "/" pattern?

```
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain web(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/", "/hello").permitAll();
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
}
```

When I entered localhost:8080/, I expect to see the page, not sign in page.

Comment: Is it working correctly on "/hello"?

Comment: yes it's working on /hello url..

Answer (score 2):

I found a answer.
There was no mapped paged with "/".
After I map the "/" page, it work.
I thought that it should be shown White page, but it seems like if start page is white page, then it print log in page even though there is permitted by permitAll.

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(){
        return "hello";
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello2")
    public String hello2(){
        return "hello2";
    }
//
//    @GetMapping("/")
//    public String start(){
//        return "startpage";
//    }
}
```